# How to store HTML code in ASP.NET MVC2 Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, model

I have a comment model with string property like this:

```
[Column]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment text can have all HTML tags inside (i know it's bad, but i have to). But when i update object, MVC 2 escapes all HTML tags.

Updating method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int ID=0)
{
        Comment comment= ID == 0
            ? new Comment ()
            : commentRepository.Comments.First(x => x.ID == ID);

        TryUpdateModel(comment);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commentRepository.Save(comment);
            return RedirectToAction("View/" + comment.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(comment);
        }
    }
```

How can i update comment text without escaping?

P.S. Also i have problem with column type: when i switch column Text in SQL Server Express from *varchar* to *text*, updating model fails:

> The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is turn off validation for that particular input field. To do that you can add this filter to you action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Or if you want to be specific and only turn it off on that one field (maybe it will work on multiple, i haven't tested that though) do something like this:

```
[ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "YourFieldName")]
```

This will exclude you field but still check all other fields.

ADDON: Adding filters ca be done in (AFAIK) two way. Here are 2 samples:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "YourFieldName")]
public ActionResult SomeAction(...) { ... }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "YourFieldName")]
publiv ActionResult SomeAction(...) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but there is no property Exclude in ValidationInputAttribute, so i need to validate myself. But it's ok :)

Comment: By the way, i found that my ckeditor returns escaped html code, so in controller's action i already got escaped html. To have raw html i should put `htmlEncodeOutput=false` in ckeditor's config. But i had to disable validation too.

Comment: 1) That's probably new in MVC3. 2) You could try the Server.HtmlDecode(html);.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the below filter on your controller under the [HttpPost] filter;

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use the Text datatype in SQL Server, it's deprecated. Instead use Nvarchar(MAX).
- To turn off input validation for your action you have to use the ValidateInput attribute on your action method. If you use .net 4 you have to add one more line to your web.config:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>       <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that Text was deprecated. Good to know )