# Is it possible to extend the ASP.NET 4.0 RequestValidator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am running into the problem with `requestValidationMode="4.0"` where if you submit html tags in a form the request will be marked as invalid and the app will throw `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`.

The two most popular solutions are to use `requestValidationMode="2.0"` combined with `validateRequest='false'` on either a global level or keeping global as `4.0` but making a subdirectory that is listed as `2.0` in its web.config and putting all the pages that you don't want validated there.

What I would really like is to keep 4.0 but add a little logic to the 4.0 [RequestValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) class to prevent it from throwing an error if it's just HTML in a form.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is only to allow HTML you can might find this article useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324945/how-to-store-html-code-in-asp-net-mvc2-model

Comment: That may be the only way to go but then someone would have to go through all of the old code and retest everything which is why I was hoping to deal with it all in one spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid. It's right in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator.aspx).

```
namespace WebApplication4
{
    public class CustomRequestValidator : RequestValidator
    {
        protected override bool IsValidRequestString(
            HttpContext context, string value,
            RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey,
            out int validationFailureIndex)
        {
            return base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);
            //validationFailureIndex = -1;
            //return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationType="WebApplication4.CustomRequestValidator "/>
    ...
</system.web>
```